# Need to find the boundary of the element on which the user clicks

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

In my Firefox extension I need to get the element boundary on which the user clicks.

I can use document.elementFromPoint() to get the element. But I want to know how far the boundary is from the click point.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`getClientRects`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getClientRects). It will return a `ClientRectList` whcih is an array-like object of `ClientRect` objects. Those `ClientRect` objects have properties like `bottom`, `top`, `left` and `right`.

```
var rectList = element.getClientRects();
var rect = rectList[0];
alert(rect.left);
```